# I can't access a Netis WF2411 router’s configuration page

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I recently bought a router ([Netis WF2411](http://www.netis-systems.com/en/products/wireless-routers-regular/53.html#.VhNhTcs_NQM)) but I’m not able to access it’s configuration page (which should be at `192.168.1.1`).

I connected the PPPoE cable to the WAN port of the router then the laptop to the router’s LAN1 port through an Ethernet cable. The router supports PPPoE, but to be able to use it I need to access the router’s configuration page and enter the login, which puts me in a chicken and egg situation.

`ipconfig` shows that DHCP is enabled, no default gateway is set and the IP is `169.x.x.x` which means that DHCP hasn’t assigned an IP address to my laptop.

The LED of the LAN port on the router doesn’t blink, it stays on, and the connection appears to be unidentified in network and sharing center.

**Edit:** I have Vbox installed, could this lead to any conflicts?

Comment: You can manually assign an IP to your PC, for example 192.168.1.2, then have a try.

Comment: Can you check the ports open on the router. Some of the routers might have installed openWRT or similar software. Which would use ssh instead of web interface or telnet port. Just try to scan the ports and you'll find something.

Answer (score -1):

To isolate the problem for a start unplug the PPPoE from WAN.

As a first trouble shooting step as you can't access the DHCP settings until connected, try assigning your Ethernet adapter a static IP address in the 192.168.1.1xx range, or the 192.168.1.xx range and see if you can access the router page then.

If that doesn't work try a router factory reset with the ethernet to the laptop and router unplugged. Plug it back in to LAN1 and if it still isnt working try plugging it into a different LAN port.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set `default gateway` to `192.168.1.1` [IP address of router] and subnet mask to `255.255.255.0`. Enter ip IP address of your choice within IP address range and then try accessing you router.

After configuring your router I would recommend you to change the router’s IP address range to match with the address you receive via WAN so you don’t have to manually change your ip address every time you want to configure your router.

If you still not able to access your router then you must be using latest firmware which is buggy and router IP address for that firmware is `192.168.0.1` so adjust your settings accordingly.

Comment: I already tried that, no luck yet.
It's weird because on the router the WPS LED is turned on, not the SYS

Comment: trying setting same ip address and default gateway

Comment: nope, it doesn't work

Comment: try accessing it via wifi. If that doesn't solve your problem get in touch with netis customer support for your region and if you think its faulty get a replacement

Answer (score -1):

Start configuring without the PPPoE cable, but just the laptop connected to a LAN port on the router, although it should not actually matter.  You can also try powering the router off and then on again, or even doing a factory reset.  ipconfig should show a 192.168 address.  If not, you can try manually "ipconfig/release" then "ipconfig/renew".

If the LAN port on the router does not blink, try a different cable, or a different LAN port - either could possibly be bad.  Are you also sure the network port on your laptop is working?